# How do I set data and log paths when creating database using EF Core Migrations?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using EF Core Migrations to create my SQL Server database.  My company has a policy that datafiles and log files belong in certain directories, but EF Core Migrations always create the database in the default locations.  Is there any way to tell EF core the paths for the physical database files so that it will create the database using the correct paths?  I know that there is an `AttachDbFile` connection string property, but I don't see a connection string property for the log file path (probably because that has nothing to do with the connection).

Is there a way to tell EF Core what these paths are, or will I need to create my database manually because of this constraint?

Comment: Use full pathnames so files are saved in correct locations.  Are you mounting the data on a server or just creating an mdf and ldf file?  AttachDbFile should only be used when the database is not mounted on a server.  When mounted on a server you should only use the server name.   If database is being mounted use following command : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @jdweng I am mounting the DB on a server.  I'll read through the link that you provided.  Thanks.

Comment: Ignore jdweng comment, it has nothing to do with EF Core target database creation. The path from `AttachDbFile` is indeed used as path for .mdf and .ldf files. But what is "backup file path" and how do you specify it in [`CREATE DATABASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=sqlpool#syntax)?

Comment: @IvanStoev That was a typo on my part, I actually meant the log file.  I'll update the question.  And my problem with the `AttachDbFile` property is that my organization requires that log files are stored in a separate directory than the data file.